How to Display "Keywords" Property in Windows File Explorer's Details View Columns?
Following this post, I have a PowerShell script that uses ExifTool to add metadata to PDF files. Specifically, it adds a tag to a PDF's "Keywords" property. The script is available here on GitHub Gist.
However, after setting the "Keywords", I noticed that Windows File Explorer does not show this property in the columns of the detailed view. I'm looking for a way, possibly through a registry modification or a FLOSS third-party tool, to make Windows display the "Keywords" property alongside other details like Name, Type, Size, etc.
Is there a method to customize File Explorer to include this metadata field in the detailed view columns? Any guidance on achieving this or pointing towards relevant resources or tools would be greatly appreciated.
